# What cases can access modifiers be different when using inheritance?

Tags: java, java-8, access-modifiers

I've been using Java for a while, largely self-taught. But I am a bit confused about access modifiers and it's bugging me because I have the OCA exam later this week and it's the only topic that I'm not very strong with. 
If we have a class with a protected method and we extend that class and override that method using public, that's ok. We went from having a protected method to a public method. My question is, in what other cases can the access modifiers be different?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also override the public methods to private or protected.

Comment: @SumitSingh - No you can not!  The override method cannot have a more restricted access than the method being overridden.  That would violate the Liskov Substitutability Principle (LSP).  (If the signatures are different you can create a more restrictive overload.  But overloading and overriding are different things.)

Comment: Sorry if the question seems amateurish (don't know why it got downvoted) but I really have been looking for the answer all over the place and I can't seem to find the specific answer. @StephenC you're right, I have seen I can't add restriction. So going from protected to private or public to protected will not work

Comment: @SumitSingh - See 8.4.8.3. Requirements in Overriding and Hiding

Comment: No, the question is not amateurish. I didn’t downvote, speculating that someone might have found the question poorly researched?

Answer (score 4):

The exact rules are given by [JLS 8.4.8.3. Requirements in Overriding and Hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3).

> The access modifier of an overriding or hiding method must provide at least as much access as the overridden or hidden method, as follows:
>
> - If the overridden or hidden method is `public`, then the overriding or hiding method must be `public`; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method is `protected`, then the overriding or hiding method must be `protected` or `public`; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method has package access, then the overriding or hiding method must not be `private`; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

---

It must be this way.  If you could override a method with a more restrictive access, this would violate the Liskov Substitutability Principle (LSP).  The LSP says that you should be able to use an instance of a subtype wherever you can use an instance of the supertype.

Comment: And in case anyone was wondering why the case of the overridden method being `private` is not covered: You cannot override a `private` method because it’s `private`. It’s not visible in the subclass.

Comment: @OleV.V. when the subclass is an inner class of the superclass, it can see and even invoke the private method. Still, declaring a method of the same name and type does not override it.